# Related Field got invalid lookup while making a model relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-related-manager

I am trying to make relationships traversing through different models but am getting this error :

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: occupational_group
```

below are the models I have :

```
class LoanApplication(models.Model, TimeStampedModel):
    loan_taker = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomerProfile, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('Customer Profile'), related_name='loan_entries')


class CustomerProfile(models.Model, TimeStampedModel):

    is_copy_component = models.BooleanField(
        _('Is copy component'), default=False)
    cooperation_partner = models.ForeignKey(
        EmailUser, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('Jurisdiction'), related_name='partner_user_profile')
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        EmailUser, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('User'), related_name='user_profile')
    approval_inquiry_sent_at = models.DateTimeField(
        _('Approval inquiry sent at'), null=True, blank=True)
    email_content_customer = models.FileField(
        _('Content of the customer email'), upload_to="customer-emails/",
        blank=True)
    approved_at = models.DateTimeField(
        _('Approved at'), null=True, blank=True)



class CustomerProfilePerson(models.Model, TimeStampedModel):


    person = models.ForeignKey(
        Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name=_('Person'), related_name='customer_profile_relation')
    customer_profile = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomerProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name=_('Customer Profile'), related_name='persons')


class Person(models.Model, TimeStampedModel):

    occupational_group = models.CharField(
        _('Occupational group'), max_length=16, blank=True,
        choices=OCCUPATIONAL_GROUP_CHOICES)
```

Am trying to filter the `LoanApplication` model with the relationship of an `occupation group`, below is the list of the occupational group :

```
OCCUPATIONAL_GROUP_CHOICES = (
    ('pharmacist', _('Pharmacist')),
    ('architect', _('Architect')),
    ('doctor', _('Doctor')),
    ('consulting_eng', _('Consulting engineer')),
    ('notary', _('Notary')),
    ('psychotherapist', _('Psychotherapist')),
    ('lawyer', _('Lawyer')),
    ('tax_consultant', _('Tax Consultant')),
    ('vet', _('Vet')),
    ('sworn_auditor', _('Sworn auditor')),
    ('surveyor', _('Surveyor')),
    ('auditor', _('Auditor')),
    ('dentist', _('Dentist')),
    ('other', _('Other')),
)
```

So this is my query below but failing :

```
LoanApplication.objects.filter(loan_taker__persons__person__occupational_group__in: ['pharmacist'])
```

Am getting this exception :

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: occupational_group
```

Comment: `loan_taker__persons__person__occupational_group='pharmacist'` (with double underscores).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, sorry about that typo, but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you query with `Person.objects.filter(occupational_group='pharmacist')`? Looks like a field is missing in your models.

Comment: This one works `Person.objects.filter(occupational_group='pharmacist')` @WillemVanOnsem, but I want the relationship all away form `LoanApplication`

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdrils: yes, but we can gradually make the query more complex to see where it "breaks"

Comment: Does `CustomerProfilePerson.objects.filter(person__occupational_group='pharmacist')` works?

Comment: This works as well `CustomerProfilePerson.objects.filter(person__occupational_group='pharmacist')` @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235065/discussion-between-lutaaya-huzaifah-idris-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass a parameter to the function with a *colon* (`:`), not an equal sign (`=`), you thus should filter with:

```
LoanApplication.objects.filter(
    loan_taker__persons__person__occupational_group__in=['pharmacist']
)
```

since you only match with a list with *one* item, you can replace this with:

```
LoanApplication.objects.filter(
    loan_taker__persons__person__occupational_group='pharmacist'
)
```